# NSIS - file in PLUGINSDIR doesn't execute

Tags: plugins, nsis

```
Function .onInit
  InitPluginsDir
  ; check registry for installed version...
Function End
Section "other" OTHER
  !define SOME_FILE "file.exe"
  SetOutPath "$PLUGINSDIR"
  File /nonfatal "${SOME_FILE}"
  ExecWait '"$PLUGINSDIR\${SOME_FILE}" /q /norestart'
SectionEnd
```

I have replaced TEMP (which I would delete at the end) with PLUGINSDIR, because it makes sense to use NSIS's own temporary directory.

But it doesn't work, the execution doesn't happen.

Am I doing it right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks correct to me.

Are you sure the file exists? Remove the /nonfatal maybe.

Maybe anti virus getting in the way? Try [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to see why process creation fails...

Comment: Thank you, I found - a typo ! NSIS is always so friendly, it works even when it shouldn't...

Comment: @Thalia thats not very friendly to a programmer :)